# Is its grammatically correct to say "As we grow old we will encounter many a situations together.."?

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I know we can use "many situations" instead. But I wanted to know if "many a situations" makes sense.. Tia

Comment: It is not correct, "a" applies to **singular nouns**.

Comment: No it doesn't.  Your needs may be better met on our sister site [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'many a situations' is incorrect, but

'many a situation' is correct, and means 'many situations'.

'many a' + (a singular countable noun)

I've read many a book.

"I've told you many a time not to ride your bike on the pavement."

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/many-a-time

Comment: Don't forget that the OP used "situation**s**", with an ***s***.